# Saving 3D masked array

Tags: python, arrays, save, mask, gdal

I'm trying to save a `3D masked_array` of data to a file using the following code:

```
print "Writing results to a file..."
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

fileName = 'path_to_folder/FLENAME.tif'
NumberOfBands = 46

new_dataset = driver.Create( fileName, 2400, 2400, NumberOfBands,gdal.GDT_Float32)
new_dataset = None

for band in range( NumberOfBands ):
    new_dataset.GetRasterBand(band + 1).WriteArray(DATA[band,:,:])
```

With this I get the error:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'`

I tried it without GetRasterband and got `'NoneType' object is not attainable`

Originally tried `np.save` as an alternative but it was not implemented and was advised to try this method instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Original error was solved thanks to Kevin's suggestion.
However after saving the file, checking it contained the required data revealed that all values were 0.0.

-This problem was solved using Mike T's suggestion. However it only seems to save the original unmasked array, not the required `masked_array`.

The DATA in question is a masked (`masked_array`) MODIS file of surface reflectance. Where the pixels that aren't required are the values that are masked.

Comment: With the [immediate problem fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31812161/838992) - you need to produce a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - in particular here we need to know what is in the `DATA` variable - are there indeed non-zero values in at least some of the bands?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post. I hope it is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem by changing the data mask to:

`mask = np.where( quality == 0, 1, 0 )`

and then multiplying the mask with the original data when saving it as below:

```
for band in range( NumberOfBands ):
    out_band=new_dataset.GetRasterBand(band + 1)
    out_band.WriteArray( databand[band,:,:] * mask[band] )

new_dataset = band = None
```

I believe the problem may have been that applying the mask to the original data array produced a masked array which contained all the original data values and a mask of true false values. When saved and read back in the file ignored the mask part of the saved array and then plotted all the original values. This was fixed as above by multiplying a mask by the data thus saving only the values permitted by the mask and solving the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading [Gotchas in the GDAL and OGR Python Bindings](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas). In general, you can debug a bit better by enabling exceptions, at the top:

```
gdal.UseExceptions()
```

And as to why you are seeing all 0.0 values is that you probably need to write the dataset, by dereferencing `band` and `new_dataset`. This can be done at the bottom with:

```
new_dataset = band = None  # save, close
```

---

To write masked arrays, you need to set a NoDataValue. E.g., if you want -9999.0 to represent no data, then:

```
NODATA = -9999
for bdx in range(new_dataset.RasterCount):
    band = new_dataset.GetRasterBand(bdx + 1)
    band.SetNoDataValue(NODATA)
    band.WriteArray(DATA[bdx].filled(NODATA))
new_dataset = band = None  # save, close
```

---

You may also consider using something more Pythonic, see [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio). E.g.:

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open(fileName, 'w', 'GTiff', 2400, 2400, NumberOfBands, dtype='f',
                   masked=True, nodata=NODATA) as r:
    r.write(DATA.astype('f'))
```

Comment: Adding that line at the end did solve the 0.0 value problem thank you. I forgot to mention earlier (and will edit my post) that the data I'm trying to save is a `masked_array` It is now saving a file, but it's the original without the masks in place

Comment: I also tried your rasterio suggestion, however the module is not implemented and unfortunately I do not have the necessary privileges to install it where I work.

Comment: Thank you, Is the NODATA part masking the array? as DATA in my case is an array where bad quality pixels have been masked and those with the fill values (32767) have then also been masked, or should I change this second mask to be NODATA?

Comment: Sorry just realised what the -99999 is for. When I seem to run that It changes the output slightly but has not masked all that I had before? It seems to have masked the Quality fine but not the fill values. When I run the code with NODATA=0 it has the desired output but with the problem of all masked values are now 0 which effects the mean etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_dataset = None
```

Try deleting this line. Otherwise, all attempts to access an attribute of `new_dataset` after this will fail.

Comment: That seemed to solve the `NoneType` error, thank you. But it seems to have written a blank file as in all values are 0.0?

Comment: Sorry, can't say I've got any experience with `gdal`... I was hoping there weren't going to be any other problems hiding behind the first one.